# Django WebSocket Tutorial

Tags: django, websocket, synchronization

I'm developing a simple online game In Django. I've searched a lot, but was not able to find an step by step tutorial on how to use WebSockets in Django. I'll appreciate it if you suggest me a tutorial.

Comment: Hello, I was wondering same issue. What did you decide to use?

Comment: As mentioned in the correct answer, https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll need django-channels:
https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/